# How to create a grid header using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can a bootstrap grid be styled with a simple header like the picture below?

When I try changing the background color of the first row, the color doesn't extend to the edge of the grid because of the grid padding.  When I remove the left/right grid padding, it messes up the rounded corners.

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: solid 1px black; border-radius: 10px; max-width: 400px">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">Name</div>
    <div class="span3">Count</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">Joe</div>
    <div class="span3">10</div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">Bob</div>
    <div class="span3">7</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help? [rounded corners on divs with background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484820/rounded-corners-on-divs-with-background-color).

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="border: solid 1px black; border-radius: 10px; max-width: 400px; padding: 0px">
    <div class="row-fluid" style="background-color: #f0f0f0; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-top-right-radius: 10px;">
        <div class="span3">Name</div>
        <div class="span3">Count</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">Joe</div>
        <div class="span3">10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">Bob</div>
        <div class="span3">7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those cases where you probably should be using a table. Screen reader users will appreciated it, and Bootstrap has styles built in that should help.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables

Comment: An interesting idea but I couldn't find any rule of thumb on when tables are preferable to grids in bootstrap.

Comment: There's no rule of thumb for Bootstrap. It's good web practice, period. Tabular data generally should go in tables.

Comment: How is data in a grid not tabular data?

Comment: I don't believe I said that it wasn't. An apple in an orange peel is still an apple. :-) A complete table, with header, body, and footer, is a good way to present data in an accessible manner. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is why are so many people using the bootstrap grid for tabular data instead of tables?  I'm not debating you here, just sorting out the use cases.

Comment: For example? I haven't seen that, and Bootstrap provides table styles for a reason.

Comment: I think @LeeWhitney might be getting confused on grid-ness. Bootstrap's grid is a logical layout from design school. Table's grid is physical representation of matrix data. Use Bootstrap's grid to layout logical UI components. Use tables to structure matrix data for the screen.

Comment: @Virmundi Excellent distinction. I'd extend to say that if you're creating headers for a *design grid*, you're doing it wrong. (Overstated, but you get the point. If you have a definition of a column that's all of the same "type", ask yourself if you're laying out a page or presenting tabular data.)